# Summing large matrices of image data efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

How do I sum large `(100, 1024, 1024) .npz` files most efficiently? Is there a better file format to store python data of the given dimensions?

I currently use this to sum the matrices:

```
summed_matrix = np.sum([np.load(file) for file in files_list])
```

This exceeds my available memory.

Comment: How many files do you have to handle? Will you always perform an addition (or an associative/commutative operation)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, you're loading all files at once and only then begin summing. If memory is a concern, a better approach would be to read and add one at a time:

```py
summed_matrix = np.zeros((100, 1024, 1024))

for file in files_list:
    summed_matrix += np.load(file)
```

Comment: Makes total sense. How is the performance compared to list comprehensions with curved braces (generator, i think)? Would this work in this case?

Comment: @Swoopoo It should, but I can't vouch for `np.sum`. It would definitely work with the built-in `sum`, though

Answer (score 5):

You could try a generator with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`numpy.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html):

```
from functools import reduce

summed_matrix = reduce(np.add, (np.load(file) for file in files_list))

# or functional-style
summed_matrix = reduce(np.add, map(np.load, files_list))
```

Comment: Note the result (in `summed_matrix`) is a generator in this case. The generator appear to contain all the loaded arrays so it is not very useful.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I was actually setting up a minimal example to double check that. Then one needs to use `functools.reduce` instead

Comment: This new code works better. Thanks for the fix. Note the `+=` version is certainly more efficient because of an in-place addition being performed by Numpy instead of an out-of-place (despite the `for` loop).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I tested all approaches on 10/100/1000 files and their timing is virtually identical

Comment: This is strange, maybe you cache is large enough to make this nearly as fast or you have a Numpy version without this optimization (or a very new one having additional optimizations for the `a=a+b` case). I tested without the `np.load` which should be the main bottleneck here anyway.

Comment: @JérômeRichard honestly I don't know (I used numpy 1.24.2). I initially tested on (10, 10, 10) arrays. I tested again on (100, 1024, 1024) arrays for 10 files and I get a slight difference 2.5s (`+=`) vs 2.6s (`reduce`). If you want me to check a particular setting let me know, or if you want to add timing results feel free to edit my answer (or add your own), that would be interesting. It would also be nice to have OP's feedback with the real data.